# Good way to deal with alpha channels in 8-bit bitmap? - OpenGL - C++

Tags: c++, opengl, alpha-transparency

I am loading bitmaps with OpenGL to texture a 3d mesh. Some of these bitmaps have alpha channels (transparency) for some of the pixels and I need to figure out the best way to

1. obtain the values of transparency for each pixel

and

1. render them with the transparency applied

Does anyone have a good example of this? Does OpenGL support this?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's generally best to convert your bitmap data to 32-bit so that each channel (R,G,B,A) gets 8 bits. When you upload your texture, specify a 32bit format.

Then when rendering, you'll need to `glEnable(GL_BLEND);` and set the blend function, eg: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`. This tells OpenGL to mix the RGB of the texture with that of the background, using the alpha of your texture.

If you're doing this to 3D objects, you might also want to turn off back-face culling (so that you see the back of the object through the front) and sort your triangles back-to-front (so that the blends happen in the correct order).

If your source bitmap is 8-bit (ie: using a palette with one colour specified as the transparency mask), then it's probably easiest to convert that to RGBA, setting the alpha value to 0 when the colour matches your transparency mask.

Some hints to make things (maybe) look better:

- Your alpha channel is going to be an all-or-nothing affair (either 0x00 or 0xff), so apply some blur algorithm to get softer edges, if that's what you're after.
- For texels (texture-pixels) with an alpha of zero (fully transparent), replace the RGB colour with the closest non-transparent texel. When texture coordinates are being interpolated, they wont be blended towards the original transparency colour from your BMP.

Comment: @geofftnz Yeah. Unfortunately, the bitmaps are in archives I cannot modify so I will need to work with them as in. Can you clarify about what I should convert to RGBA? Thank you!

Comment: are you talking about BMP files?

Comment: Yeah. The 8 bit bmp files are in archives that I cannot modify so I need to load them as is.

Comment: @geofftnz Sorry I am confused. In an 8 bit bitmap you mentioned one color is specified as a transparency map. Does that apply for the whole image? If so, I could just get that value and key that out in each texture when I render it correct? Now the question is how to obtain it...

Comment: @Flarmar He didn't necessarily mean that you had to convert the files. If you can't convert the files, you should convert the data at load time.

Comment: @Flarmar yes, convert at load time. From memory BMPs don't have any support for transparency, so it's up to the application. The options are: A specific index in the palette is treated as transparent (usually either 0 or 255), or a specific RGB value (magenta 0xff00ff seems to be the most common) indicates transparency.

Answer (score 1):

If your pixmap are 8-bit single channel they are either grayscale or use a palette. What you first need to do is converting the pixmap data into RGBA format. For this you allocate a buffer large enough to hold a 4-channel pixmap of the dimensions of the original file. Then for each pixel of the pixmap use that pixel's value as index into the palette (look up table) and put that color value into the corresponding pixel in the RGBA buffer. Once finished, upload to OpenGL using *glTexImage2D*.

If your GPU supports fragment shaders (very likely) you can do that LUT transformation in the shader: Upload the 8-bit pixmal as a GL_RED or GL_LUMINANCE 2D texture. And upload the palette as a 1D GL_RGBA texture. Then in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler1D palette_lut;

void main()
{
    float palette_index = texture2D(texture,gl_TexCoord[0].st).r;
    vec4 color = texture1D(palette_lut, palette_index);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Blended rendering conflicts with the Z buffer algorithm, so you must sort your geometry back-to-front for things to look properly. As long as this affects objects at a whole this is rather simple, but it becomes tedious if you need to sort the faces of a mesh rendering each and every frame. A method to avoid this is breaking down meshes into convex submeshes (of course a mesh that's convex already can not be broken down further). Then use the following method:

- **Enable** face culling
- for convex_submesh in sorted(meshes, far to near):

  - set face culling to *front* faces (i.e. the backside gets rendered)
  - render convex_submesh
  - set face culling to *back* faces (i.e. the fronside gets rendered)
  - render convex_submesh again